# Resolving differential equations manually - particular solution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to find a particular solution to this equation. I have no idea for resolvint it, except trying some functions. If you have any method to help me it would be nice !

Here is the differential equation (this equation comes from a simple electronic circuit) :

$$\frac{dVc(t)}{dt} + \frac{R_1+R_2}{R_1R_2C}*Vc(t) = \frac{Asin(wt)}{R_1C}$$ where t is between 0 and T/2, and $$w = \frac{2*Pi}{T}$$

Whatever t, the differential equation is : 
$$\frac{dVc(t)}{dt} + \frac{R_1+R_2}{R_1R_2C}*Vc(t) = \frac{A|sin(wt)|}{R_1C}$$

All the constant are positive.

Thank you very much and have a nice day !

Comment: Why are you showing two different equations ? (with a non-trivial difference)

Comment: One is defined on the interval between 0 and T/2, the other is defined whatever the value of t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

I will give a solution without those annoying constants, which can be restored later. The solution to the first equation is just the start of the solution of the second.

We have

$$v'+v=|\sin t|$$

or, multiplying by $e^t$,

$$(ve^t)'=e^t|\sin t|,$$

$$v=e^{-t}\int_0^t e^t|\sin t|dt.$$

During the first half-period,

$$v=e^{-t}\int_0^t e^t\sin t\,dt.$$

Then during the second half, you need to change the sign,

$$v=e^{-t}\left(\int_0^\pi e^t\sin t\,dt-\int_\pi^t e^t\sin t\,dt\right)=e^{-t}\left(\int_0^\pi e^t\sin t\,dt-e^\pi\int_0^{t-\pi} e^t\sin t\,dt\right).$$

And you can continue to the next half-periods.
$$e^{-t}\left((1-e^\pi)\int_0^\pi e^t\sin t\,dt+e^{2\pi}\int_0^{t-2\pi} e^t\sin t\,dt\right)$$

$$e^{-t}\left((1-e^\pi+e^{2\pi})\int_0^\pi e^t\sin t\,dt-e^{3\pi}\int_0^{t-3\pi} e^t\sin t\,dt\right)$$
$$\cdots$$

---

An antiderivative of $e^t\sin t$ is $e^t(\sin t-\cos t)$.

Comment: Thank you ! Nice explanation. And the result of this integration $$v=\int_0^t e^t\sin t\,dt.$$ is $$\frac{e^t}{2}*(\sin t\ -\cos t)$$ ?

Comment: @Jess: yep, typo.

Comment: Just to be sure, once I have found the particular solution of this equation, I need to add the solutions of the homogeneous differential equation to have the solutions of the differetial equation ?

Comment: @Jess: yes, there is nothing different.

Comment: Thank you I will try to see if my/your results work !

Comment: Hi, 

I think that there is an error but I am not sure at this line : $$v=e^{-t}\left(\int_0^\pi e^t\sin t\,dt-\int_\pi^t e^t\sin t\,dt\right)=e^{-t}\left(\int_0^\pi e^t\sin t\,dt-e^\pi\int_0^{t-\pi} e^t\sin t\,dt\right).$$ as $$\sin( t+\pi) = -sin(t)$$ So it shoudl be $$v=e^{-t}\left(\int_0^\pi e^t\sin t\,dt-\int_\pi^t e^t\sin t\,dt\right)=e^{-t}\left(\int_0^\pi e^t\sin t\,dt+e^\pi\int_0^{t-\pi} e^t\sin t\,dt\right).$$ Then $$e^{-t}\left((1+e^\pi+e^{2\pi})\int_0^\pi e^t\sin t\,dt+e^{3\pi}\int_0^{t-3\pi} e^t\sin t\,dt\right)$$

Comment: I think I am wrong as physically it doesn't means anything ...as v seems to go to infinite if t goes to infinite

Comment: @Jess: what makes you say that ?

Comment: I forgot a lot of my math (it wasn t so far, though) When you did :

$$\int_\pi^t e^t\sin t\,dt = e^\pi\int_0^{t-\pi} e^t\sin t\,dt$$

you did an integration by substitution ? $$x = t-\pi$$ ? Isn't it ? How did you do ?

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*:

This is a linear ODE and the solution is given by

$$V_c(t) \cdot e^{\int \frac{R_1+R_2}{R_1 R_2 C} dt} =\int\frac{A\sin(\omega t)}{R_1 C} e^{\int \frac{R_1+R_2}{R_1 R_2 C}dt} dt$$

Comment: Er, are you sure ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust My bad, how about now?

Comment: Yes, better like this. But the second equation is more interesting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.